# Custom Hamcrest matcher to compare maps

Tags: java, junit

I am new to Java and have written a custom matcher to compare two maps because the error message from either `JUnit` or Hamcrest is not detailed enough. The code I wrote works, but I welcome critiques or comments to make it better.

One question:

Right now, I hard-coded my map to `<String, String>` but would like to be more generic. My first attempt was to use `<Object, Object>`, which resulted in a compiler error.

Here is my matcher:

```
package net.southeastwind.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher;


public class MapEquivalent extends TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<Map<String, String>> {
    private Map<String, String> m_expected;

    public MapEquivalent(Map<String, String> expected) {
        m_expected = expected;
    }

    public static MapEquivalent mapEquivalent(Map<String, String> expected) {
        return new MapEquivalent(expected);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("Maps are equivalent");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(Map<String, String> actual, Description description) {
        boolean matched = true;

        Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
        keys.addAll(actual.keySet());
        keys.addAll(m_expected.keySet());

        for (String key: keys) {
            String expectedValue = m_expected.get(key);
            String actualValue = actual.get(key);

            if (null == expectedValue) {
                matched = false;
                description
                    .appendText("\n\t\tOnly in actual: {").appendValue(key)
                    .appendText(": ").appendValue(actualValue).appendText("}");
            } else if (null == actualValue) {
                matched = false;
                description
                    .appendText("\n\t\tOnly in expected: {").appendValue(key)
                    .appendText(": ").appendValue(expectedValue).appendText("}");
            } else if (!actualValue.equals(expectedValue)) {
                matched = false;
                description
                    .appendText("\n\t\tValues differ: ")
                    .appendText("actual={").appendValue(key).appendText(": ").appendValue(actualValue).appendText("}")
                    .appendText(", expected={").appendValue(key).appendText(": ").appendValue(expectedValue).appendText("}");

            }
        }

        return matched;
    }
}
```

Sample test and output:

```
@Test
public void compareMaps() {
    Map<String, String> expected = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("alias", "haiv");
        put("uid", "501");
        put("admin", "no");
    }};

    Map<String, String> actual = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("alias", "haiv");
        put("uid", "502");
        put("shell", "bash");
    }};

    assertThat("Error 6a3429f7", actual, is(mapEquivalent(expected)));
    // CustomMatchersTest > compareMaps FAILED
    //     java.lang.AssertionError: Error 6a3429f7
    //     Expected: Maps are equivalent
    //          but:
    //                 Values differ: actual={"uid": "502"}, expected={"uid": "501"}
    //                 Only in actual: {"shell": "bash"}
    //                 Only in expected: {"admin": "no"}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the output looks really Nice :-)

Consider the following points:

- I think you'll have NPE's when you pass null maps
- There's a lot of different implementations of `Map`. If you have a `SortedMap`, it can pass, even though the sorting is different.
- How does the message look, when the maps do not have the same size? Is the message clear enough?
- The message "Expected: Maps are equivalent, but" is a bit strange? They are not equivalent, are they?
- `m_expected`: Naming convention: should be `mExpected`. But to be honest, I'd go with `expected`.
- Sadly, it only works with `String`...

Hope this helps...

Comment: I made many changes based on your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One tip is you can genericise this quite easily using k,v (Java Generics). This way you can specify if it's Map or any other variation. Generics help you abstract away from a specific object and the ability to write methods that are not covered of the underlying data type (such as your use case)

For more details refer to this... 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: Do you mean generalize? If you're talking about key value pairs you might want to make that more clear.